# Anybody can tell me why this sentence works fine: System.out.println(p[i]);

Tags: java

Reading about cryptography, can not understand why the indicated line of code print data:

```
Provider p[] = Security.getProviders()
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(p[i]); // <<<--- THIS LINE
```

why this print out data if it's not a string, it's a provider object

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Why do you assume it would only accept strings?

Answer (score 5):

because `println()` accept many types, there are many *signature* of this method for example :

```
println(int i){...}               //when you set int you call this
println(String i){...}            //when you set String you call this
println(boolean i){...}           //when you set boolean you call this
println(char i){...}              //when you set char you call this
println(java.lang.Object i){...}  //when you set Object you call this
... and so on
```

Take a look here [java.lang.System](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#72)

Comment: Please provide example with `Object` type

Comment: That's right, println accepts an object as a parameter. Many thanks, you are very kind.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: All the classes in Java (not most of them as stated below, thanks for that) have toString() method which returns String representation of an object, the same applies for Provider class. When writing your own class you can override toString() method, meaning that you can write the method called toString() which will then be called whenever you try to access that object as a String (for example in System.out.println()).

Hope this helps, if not, just google toString().

Comment: "Most of the classes": Object has toString, all classes derive from Object. You do the math.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `println()` calls the Object's `toString()` method (i.e. Provider's `toString()`) to print the string representation of the object. (If Provider class has implemented `toString()` else the default `toString()` which is inherited from Object class)

`Javadoc link` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)

> public void println(Object x)
>
> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().
>
> Parameters:
>
> x - The Object to be printed.

**If Object (i.e.Provider in your case) class hasn't overridden default java.lang.Object's class `toString()` then what would it display?**

It actually prints the class name + "@" symbol + the hex value of Object's hashcode method. (hashcode is also inherited from Object class)

```
public class Solution {
    private int i;

    public Solution() {
        this.i = 10;
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        System.out.println(solution);
        // what is default toString prints?
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(solution.hashCode()));
    }
}
```

Sample Run

```
Solution@5eba06ff
5eba06ff
```

**If Object (i.e.Provider in your case) has overridden default java.lang.Object's class `toString()` then what would it display?**

It actually prints what you intent to print in toString().

```
public class Solution {
    private int i;

    public Solution() {
        this.i = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Solution [i=" + i + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        System.out.println(solution);
    }
}
```

Sample Run

```
Solution [i=10]
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, whenever we try to 1. print an object directly 2. or concat an object with string directly, the **toString method is automatically called**. By default, to string prints class name @ hashcode

Like in your example, **`p[i].toString()` is happening**.

Since, object class is parent of every class directly or indirectly, all of its 11 functions (including toString() ) are inherited in the child class.

Provider class overrides the function toString() from the `Hashtable<Object,Object>` class. **This overridden toString() returns a string with the name and the version number of this provider**.

Answer (score 0):

public class ExamineSecurity {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(p[i]);
            for (Enumeration e = p[i].keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
                System.out.println("\t" + e.nextElement());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

If we run this program with the 1.2 Sun security provider, we get this output:

Class Definition

SUN version 1.2
        Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.SHA

```
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHAwithDSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.3.14.3.2.13
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.10040.4.3
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHA-1/DSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.DSS
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHA1withDSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.3.14.3.2.13
    AlgorithmParameters.DSA
    KeyFactory.DSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.10040.4.3
    Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.SHA1
    AlgorithmParameterGenerator.DSA
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    MessageDigest.MD5
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.OID.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    MessageDigest.SHA-1
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.OID.1.3.14.3.2.12
    Signature.DSA
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.3.14.3.2.12
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.3.14.3.2.27
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHA/DSA
```

Two things are readily apparent from this example. First, the strings that contain only an engine name and an algorithm implement the expected operations that we listed in Table 8-1. Second, as we mentioned in the section on the Provider class, security providers often leverage the fact that the Provider class is a subclass of the Properties class to provide properties that may make sense only to other classes that are part of the provider package. Hence, the signature algorithm 1.3.14.3.2.13 may make sense to one of the classes in the Sun security provider,`but it is not a string that will necessarily not make sense to other developers. In fact, those aliases--including the ones that are prefaced by OID--do have meanings within the cryptography standards world`, but for our purposes we'll stick with the standard algorithm names that we listed earlier.

Answer (score -2):

The toString() method of the class Provider seems to be implemented.

Comment: It is always implemented, even if it comes from `Object` type.

Comment: Who the hell needs to downvote this? Provider does have toString implemented, and that is how the line in question works.

Comment: This answer is a) vague and incomplete and B) just stating something - no explanation whatsoever. But not my downvote.

Comment: Yes, there are some guys who downvote other people's answers without commenting